Zeros of a reciprocal polynomial
Let $k$ be a positive even integer and consider the polynomial
$$
f_k(z)=z^k(z+1)^k+z^k+(z+1)^k.
$$
Numerical computation suggests that the zeros of this polynomial behave as follows: If $\mbox{Re}(z)\gt -1/2$, then the zeros lie on the unit circle. If $\mbox{Re}(z)\lt -1/2$, then all the zeros lie on the unit circle centered at $-1$. Otherwise, the rest of the zeros lie on $\mbox{Re}(z)= -1/2$.
Here is a picture of the zeros for $k=120$:

I would like to prove formally that this is true, but I don't know where to start. I tried for instance assuming that $\mbox{Re}(z)\gt -1/2$ and then trying to show that $|z^k|=1$ by expressing $z^k$ in terms of a polynomial in $(z+1)^k$, but this didn't work.
I also noticed that $f_k(z)$ is a reciprocal polynomial, so I tried looking at results on this direction, but all the results say something like: if some condition holds then all the zeros lie in the unit circle, but of course in this case not all of them lie in the unit circle, and I don't know how to adapt those results in this case. I would also like to know the separation of the zeros, I'm thinking that this is $O(1/k)$.

Are you asking about the asymptotic location of the roots? Because for small $k$ (I tested $k=3$ and $k=5$ with WolframAlpha) the roots do not lie on those circles or on that line, at least not exactly.

Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that $k$ is even. And yes, I would be satisfied with the asymptotic location of the roots, but if it's possible to show that for any $k\geq 4$ the roots are exactly on those circles or that line, that would be great

I am now fairly sure that you conjecture is true for even $k$. With the substitution $w = (z-\omega)/(z - \omega^2)$ where $\omega = \exp(2 \pi i /3)$ one gets $f_k(z) = w^m g_k(w^3)$ with $m \in { 0, 1, 2 }$. It remains to show that all roots of $g_k$ are on the negative real axis, but I haven't solved that part yet.

For example, $f_8(z) = w^2 g_8(w^3)$ with $g_8(w) = 108 w^4+1512 w^3+3321 w^2+1512 w+108$. The roots of $g_8$ are $-0.0876, -0.5, -2, -11.412$.

I also wouldn't know how to show that all roots of $g_k$ are on the negative real axis. I think I found another way to prove the conjecture. I'll only give a quick sketch: Let $h(t)=e^{ikt/2}f_k(e^{it})=2\cos(tk/2)+(2\cos(t/2))^{-k}$, so that a zero of $h(t)$ is a zero of $f_k(z)$ on the unit circle. Then $f(2m\pi/k)$ is positive or negative according to the parity of $m$, where $m$ is an integer between $-k/3$ and $k/3$. Therefore, if $k=6n$, $h$ changes sign $2k/3=4n$ times, so that there are $4n$ zeros on the unit circle. For the rest we can use the transformations from Empy2's answer

Are you sure about that identity? For example, $h(0) = f(1) = 2^{k+1} + 1$, but $2\cos(tk/2)+(2\cos(t/2))^{-k} = 2 + 2^{-k}$ for $z=0$. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something?

Oh I'm very sorry, on my notes I was working with a different function. So, let $\alpha_k(z)=1+1/z^k+1/(z+1)^k=\frac{f_k(z)}{z^k(z+1)^k}$ ($\alpha_k$ and $f_k$ have the same zeros), the function $h_k$ I'm considering is not like I defined it above, but $h(t)=e^{ikt/2}\alpha_k(e^{it})$.

See Edit2 below, which confirms OP's conjectures.
It can be written $$\left(\frac1z\right)^k+\left(\frac1{z+1}\right)^k=-1$$
If $z+1$ is outside the unit circle, that is very close to $$z^{-k}\approx -1$$
so you get a lot of roots near the unit circle.
Similarly if $z$ is outside the unit circle there are solutions with $z+1$ near the unit circle.
When the real part is $-1/2$, both terms have the same absolute value and $z+1=-\bar z$.  If $k$ is even then the two terms are conjugate, so you get a solution whenever $\Re(z^{-k})=-1/2$.
EDIT
Near $\exp(2\pi i/3)$.  Suppose $k$ is a multiple of $6$.  A first estimate of $z$ is to ignore $z+1$
then $$z\approx \exp{(\frac {2\pi}3-\frac\pi k)i}$$
Then $|z+1|\approx 1+\sqrt3\pi/(2k)$ so $|z+1|^{-k}\approx \exp(-\sqrt3\pi/2)\approx 0.066$
So I think $z$ needs a correction of size $O(0.066/k)$
EDIT2:
The $2k$ roots are all on the three shapes namely the two circles and the straight line.
Let $\omega=\exp(2i\pi/3)$.
First, if $k=2\pmod6$, there is a double root at both $\omega$ and $\omega^2$, and if $k=4\pmod6$, there is a single root at both points.
The other roots all form groups of six, in the form $$z,\frac1z,-1-z,-1-\frac1z,\frac{-1}{1+z},\frac{-z}{1+z}$$
Two are on the line $\Re(z)=-1/2$, two are on the unit circle and two are on the circle, radius 1, centred at -1.
That will account for all $2k$ roots.
Take the straight line between $\omega$ and $\omega^2$.  Its angle runs from $2\pi/3$ to $4\pi/3$.  When raised to the $-k$ power, the angle runs from $-2k\pi/3$ to $-4k\pi/3$.
Consider $k=6n$, the other cases are similar.  The angle of $z^{-k}$ runs from $-4n\pi$ to $-8n\pi$, and the absolute value of $z^{-k}$ remains above $1$.  So $z^{-k}$ crosses the line with real part $-1/2$, $4n$ times as $z$ runs from $\omega$ to $\omega^2$.  As mentioned above  each of those $4n$ points is a root.
By symmetry, these roots form pairs $-1/2\pm yi$.  Each pair forms a sextet as mentioned above, giving $12n=2k$ roots.

Can we way how close is $z^{-k}$ to -1 when $z+1$ is outside the unit circle? Also, can we specify how outside of the unit circle does it have to be? I think the problem lies mainly when $z$ is close to $\rho=e^{2\pi i/3}$

Let $\omega=e^{i\pi/3}$.  The first zero near $\omega^2$ is $\omega^2+z/k+O(k^{-2})$ where $\exp(-z/\omega^2)+\exp(-z/\omega)=-1$.  I think you could find $z$ numerically.

I don't know how to make all of this more precise. Again, when $k$ is even I think the zeros will actually lie exactly on one of those unit circles or exactly on that vertical line, and I know it's probably possible to show that they are within a 1/k distance of the unit circle, but I was wondering if there's any way to prove or disprove that they lie exactly on the arc.

If $z$ is a root then so are $\bar z$ and $1/z$.  So if it is not quite on the unit circle, then there is a pair of roots very close to each other.

I see, I think I get it, thank you very much for your answer. The only thing I'm still not fully satisfied is in knowing if it's possible to have one root not quite on the unit circle. So far, numerically it really seems that for even $k$ all roots are on those circles or line.
